# Javascript select Google markers for all possibilities of checkbox conditions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, checkbox, google-maps-markers

I am placing markers on a Google map. I have a number of checkboxes (19 currently) in a form that I am trying to create a dynamic "and" condition to display or not display markers.   The code works great for the individual pieces when a single checkbox is selected.   I would like to have the code take into account if multiple checkboxes are selected and only display those markers that meet all conditions not just add the ones that meet the next condition.

Givens:

1. The checkbox ids are "q"+#
2. Each Google Marker has values of true or false for each q#(checkbox) the code is below:
   createMarker(point,html,q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, q19)
3. There are many Marker Points

Need:

If checkbox 1 and 2 are checked only display those markers that have q1 = true "and" q2 = true in the createMarker variables.  However, also allow for a single checkbox to be checked and the correct Markers displayed
I need this condition for all possibilities of checkboxes being selected (1 to 19).

How can I make this work?

Current Code for single condition:

```
//loop through the checkbox questions
for (var h=1; h<20; h++) {
        //check to see if the checkbox is checked
        if (document.getElementById('q'+h).checked == true) {               
            for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) { 
                //check to see if the Marker has that variable set to true for the question it is loop through                  
                if (h == 1 && gmarkers[i].q1 == 1) {                            
                                    \\ show marker                      
                                     gmarkers[i].show();                    
                }
                if (h == 2 && gmarkers[i].q2 == 1) {                            
                   // turned off for testing    
                                       //gmarkers[i].show();                    
                }
                if (h == 3 && gmarkers[i].q3 == 1) {                            
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 4 && gmarkers[i].q4 == 1) {                            
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 5 && gmarkers[i].q5 == 1) {                            
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 6 && gmarkers[i].q6 == 1) {                            
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 7 && gmarkers[i].q7 == 1) {                            
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 8 && gmarkers[i].q8 == 1) {                            
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 9 && gmarkers[i].q9 == 1) {                            
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 10 && gmarkers[i].q10 == 1) {                          
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 11 && gmarkers[i].q11 == 1) {                          
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 12 && gmarkers[i].q12 == 1) {                          
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 13 && gmarkers[i].q13 == 1) {                          
                    gmarkers[i].show();

                }
                if (h == 14 && gmarkers[i].q14 == 1) {                          
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 15 && gmarkers[i].q15 == 1) {                          
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 16 && gmarkers[i].q16 == 1) {                          
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 17 && gmarkers[i].q17 == 1) {                          
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }
                if (h == 18 && gmarkers[i].q18 == 1) {                          
                    //gmarkers[i].show();                   
                }                   
                if (h == 19 && gmarkers[i].q19 == 1) {                          
                    //gmarkers[i].show();           
                }


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach where you did not have to iterate over each q-property of the marker:

**Use bitwise operations.**

Lets assume you have a marker with the properties q1, q3 and q5 set to true .

Instead of storing each property of the marker, use a decimal and set the bytes 1,3 and 5.

This would result in the binary value `10101` (the decimal is `21`, store it as the marker-property)

To compare this decimal with the checked checkboxes use also a decimal and set the bytes where the checkboxes are checked.

Assuming the checkboxes for q1 and q5 are checked, the binary value would be `10001`(decimal `17`)

All you have to do now is to check if the result of a bitwise `AND` of the markers property and the checkboxes-property is equal to the checkboxes-property

```
((21 & 17)>>>0===17)//returns true
```

This approach would work for up to 32 properties.

**Demo:** [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/hsPVS/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/hsPVS/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help!  This is what I was looking for. I have been able to make a few changes and get this to work for my data.  I am still struggling on how to label the checkboxes if they are in JQuery.  I need them to have a description.  I tried to pull them out but then the setMap piece does not work.  Any thought?

Comment: I think I have my above question figured out now also. Thanks again.

Comment: Here is a more simplified version, can be used with hardcoded markup: http://jsfiddle.net/yHxue/ (you only need to change the selector for the boxes)

Comment: Thanks again.  I really appreciate your help and time showing me how this works.

Comment: @Dr.Molle i need to get this to work but i can't understand the shorthand coding for the bitwise operation in javascript... and i can't event write the longhand because i dont understand the check.. can you tell me more ? : markers[m].setMap(((markers[m].props & props)>>>0===props)
                                      ? ((props)?map:null)
                                      : null);

Comment: There is no "longhand", bitwise operators are not "shorthands". An example: let's assume a marker has a `props` -value set to integer `5`, (it's binary `101` ) and a props-value (based on the checkboxes) of 4(binary `100`). The `&` is a bitwise `AND`-operator, it will set bits that are set in both expressions(numbers). The bit that is set in both numbers is the third bit from the right, so the result will be `100`(equal to props, a successfull match). On the other hand, assume a marker-props of `2`(binary `010`), there is no bit set in both( 2 and 5).

Comment: You'll see it better(the bits that have been set in both values)when you write the binary values among each other, however it's not easy to explain it in a comment, you better search for a tutorial for bitwise operations