# Filter Google Map markers by multiple groups with categories

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've managed to make filtering of markers by category by browsing through this website. However I'm stuck when I need to filter multiple groups of categories.

Something like:

> Type : Type 1, Type 2, Type 3, Type 4
>
> Class: Class 1, Class 2, Class 3

Here's what I have so far (made it as simple as I can): http://jsbin.com/rahur/1/edit?html,js,output

For quick glance here's the main portion:

```
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);
            bounds.extend(pos);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:pos,
                map:map,
                'sgroup': markers[i][3]['sgroup'],
                'sclass': markers[i][3]['sclass'],
                'stype':  markers[i][3]['stype']
            });
           
            markersType.push(marker);
        } 
  function toggleMarkers(category, visible) {
                jQuery(markersType).each(function(id, marker) {
                    if (jQuery.inArray( category, marker.stype ) != -1)
                        marker.setVisible(visible);
                });
            }
  $( "#type-school-list input:checkbox" ).click(function() {
            $('#type-school-list input:checkbox').each(function () {
                toggleMarkers($(this).val(), $(this).is(":checked"));
            }); 
   });
```

Not sure if I'm on the right track since several things I've tried do not work properly. If you could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528115/javascript-select-google-markers-for-all-possibilities-of-checkbox-conditions

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with three different categories and this is my solution:

```
Javascript
<script> 

var markers = [];
var iterator = 0;
    var line = []


function initialize(){
        var i;
        var infowindowArr = [];
        var chania = new google.maps.LatLng(35.513829800000000000,24.018036700000040000);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: chania
          }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        var newMarker;
        var image = 'some url';

        function addMarker() {
          newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(line[iterator][1],line[iterator][0]),
                map: map,
                title: line[iterator][2],
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: image
            });
            newMarker.period = line[iterator][4];
            newMarker.category = line[iterator][5];
            newMarker.section = line[iterator][6];

            newMarker.setVisible(true);

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
              });
            }           
            markers.push(newMarker);
          iterator++;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            addMarker();

        }, i * 50);
        } 

    }



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
//each array of this array has number of fields equal to the number of filters for its filter category, its makes more sense if you see the html code
var filtersArr = [
[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],
[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],
[false,false,false,false,false,false,false]
];


function filterMarkers(event) 
{
    //hide all markers
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);           
    }

    //get checkbox clicked value and id
    event = event || window.event; // IE
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // IE
    var pos;
    var arr = target.value;

    // Get the array filter position (and set it true or false) from the checkbox id.
```

If you see the html i hope you will figure out what im doing here. Its not preety but i had a deadline so i didnt had to do something better of it.

```
    if ( arr == 1 ) {
        pos = target.id - 8; 
    } else if ( arr == 2 ) {
        pos = target.id - 22;
    } else {
        pos = target.id;
    }
    //update filtersArray
    if (document.getElementById(target.id).checked) {

        filtersArr[arr][pos] = true;
    } else {
        filtersArr[arr][pos] = false;
    }
```

Here comes the algorithmic part, basicly what gives you the right filtred markers.

```
    //existing filters scenario
    if ( isUnchecked(filtersArr[0]) == true && isUnchecked(filtersArr[1]) == false && isUnchecked(filtersArr[2]) == false )  {
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if ( filtersArr[1][markers[i].category] == true &&  filtersArr[2][markers[i].section] == true ) {
                markers[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( isUnchecked(filtersArr[1]) == true && isUnchecked(filtersArr[0]) == false && isUnchecked(filtersArr[2]) == false )  {
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if ( filtersArr[0][markers[i].period] == true &&  filtersArr[2][markers[i].section] == true ) {
                markers[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( isUnchecked(filtersArr[2]) == true && isUnchecked(filtersArr[0]) == false && isUnchecked(filtersArr[1]) == false )  {
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if ( filtersArr[0][markers[i].period] == true &&  filtersArr[1][markers[i].category] == true ) {
                markers[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }   
    else if ( isUnchecked(filtersArr[0]) == true && isUnchecked(filtersArr[1]) == false && isUnchecked(filtersArr[2]) == true )  {//true,true,false Scenario
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if ( filtersArr[1][markers[i].category] == true ) {
                markers[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( isUnchecked(filtersArr[0]) == true && isUnchecked(filtersArr[1]) == true && isUnchecked(filtersArr[2]) == false )  {
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if ( filtersArr[2][markers[i].section] == true ) {
                markers[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( isUnchecked(filtersArr[1]) == true && isUnchecked(filtersArr[0]) == false && isUnchecked(filtersArr[2]) == true )  {
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if ( filtersArr[0][markers[i].period] == true ) {
                markers[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( isUnchecked(filtersArr[0]) == false && isUnchecked(filtersArr[1]) == false && isUnchecked(filtersArr[2]) == false )  {//false,false,false Scenario

        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if ( filtersArr[0][markers[i].period] == true && filtersArr[1][markers[i].category] == true && filtersArr[2][markers[i].section] == true  ) {
                markers[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

A function to check if all the filters of a category are unchecked

```
//checks if an array (filter category) is unchecked
function isUnchecked(arr)
{
var j;
    for(j=0;j<arr.length;j++) {
        if ( arr[j] == true) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

html

```
 <body>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<div id="filters">

<span id="perOptions">
<h4  style="color:#dd6303;font-family:roboto !important;font-size:14px;">Ιστορική    Περίοδος</h4><input type="checkbox" id="0" value="0"  onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Βυζαντινή περίοδος </br>
     <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="0" onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Ενετική    περίοδος</br>
     <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="0" onclick="filterMarkers(event)">
     <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="0" onclick="filterMarkers(event)">Κρητική   πολιτεία</br>
     <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="0" onclick="filterMarkers(event)">Νεώτεροι  χρόνοι </br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="5" value="0" onclick="filterMarkers(event)">Προϊστορικοί περίοδος</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="6" value="0" onclick="filterMarkers(event)">Οθωμανική κυριαρχία</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="7" value="0" onclick="filterMarkers(event)">Γεωμετρική   Περίοδος</br>

     </span>

    <span id="kindOptions">
    <h4  style="color:#dd6303;font-family:roboto !important;font-    size:14px;">Κατηγορία</h4>
    <input type="checkbox" id="8" value="1"    onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Αρχαιολογικός χώρος</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="9" value="1" onclick="filterMarkers(event);"   >Εκκλησία</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="10" value="1"   onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Πλατεία</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="11" value="1" onclick="filterMarkers(event);"   >Αρχιτεκτονικό Μνημείο</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="12" value="1"    onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Μουσείο</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="13" value="1" onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Τζαμί</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="14" value="1" onclick="filterMarkers(event);" >Ιστορική  Συνοικία</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="15" value="1" onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Ιστορική Συνοικία/</br>Αρχιτεκτονικό Μνημείο</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="16" value="1" onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Φρούριο</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="17" value="1" onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Χαμάμ</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="18" value="1" onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Κρήνη</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="19" value="1"   onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Αρχιτεκτονικό /</br> Πολιτιστικό Μνημείο</br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="20" value="1" onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Ιστορικοί  Οδοί</br>
     <input type="checkbox" id="21" value="1" onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Πινακοθήκη</br>

  </span>

  <span id="areaOptions">
  <h4  style="color:#dd6303;font-family:roboto !important;font-size:14px;">Δημοτική     Ενότητα</h4>
 <input type="checkbox" id="22" value="2" onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Χανίων</br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="23" value="2" onclick="filterMarkers(event);"  >Ακρωτηρίου</br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="24" value="2" onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Σούδας</br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="25" value="2" onclick="filterMarkers(event);">Θερίσου</br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="26" value="2" onclick="filterMarkers(event);" >Κεραμειών
  </span>
  </div>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same purpose of build up multiple groups of the checkbox in one project. After doing a couple of experiment, I found that each marker of an element will have one combination of data which we can combine these to construct one value as a category in google map marker.

So here is my solution. In this example I have two groups of checkbox filter as per below.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Gender: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="g1" value="F" checked="checked" onclick="clickBox()" /> Female
    <input type="checkbox" class="g1" value="M" checked="checked" onclick="clickBox()" /> Male
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Type of Practice: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="g2" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="clickBox()" /> Government
    <input type="checkbox" class="g2" value="2" checked="checked" onclick="clickBox()" /> GLC
    <input type="checkbox" class="g2" value="3" checked="checked" onclick="clickBox()" /> Private
    <input type="checkbox" class="g2" value="4" checked="checked" onclick="clickBox()" /> Oversea
    <input type="checkbox" class="g2" value="5" checked="checked" onclick="clickBox()" /> Not Practice
  </div>
</form>
```

Each element groups with class name of `g1` and `g2`. Each element will have trigger `clickBox()` which define in JavaScript.

**Google Maps**

Inside Google Map, instead of defining two categories for a marker, I just construct a combination data.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: point,
});
marker.category = gender + '_' + type_group;
gmarkers.push(marker);
```

So for `marker.category` data, combine both `gender` and `type_group` data into one. Most probably it would return as 'F_1', 'F_2' and etc depends on the data source.

After that, add the filter script as per below:

```
/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
 */
function clickBox() {
  // Create the initial group selection
  var checked = [];

  // Generate the recursive array item from each groups elements
  jQuery('.g1:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    var g1 = jQuery(this).val();

    jQuery('.g2:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
      var g2 = jQuery(this).val();
      // Construct final combination array same as gmap category value
      checked.push(g1 + '_' + g2);
    });
  });

  // Apply the visibility set to markers
  for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers[i];
    // If marker in category of array, show it
    if (jQuery.inArray(marker.category, checked) !== -1) {
      gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
    }
    else {
      gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}
```

This JS function will be trigger and response everytime any checkbox element is clicking. First, we define an empty `checked` variables. Then we create a recursive array value base on the checkbox with checked value only.

This recursive arrangement must be same as constructed in Google Map category values. Eitherwise the value will not be same. If you have more than 2 groups element, then you need to add by your self.

At the end of recursive, we push into `checked` array. Lastly, by using `inArray` comparison of jQuery, we check each of markers to match with `checked` array.