# How do I use multiple groups of multiple checkboxes, with Javascript and Google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Problem:  I would like to use multiple groups (2 groups) of multiple checkboxes (about 9 in each group) in my Google Maps api 3 application.

Background:  I am a amateur radio operator (Ham) and I would like to display my radio contacts on Google maps.  Hams are allowed to use different frequencies (Band of frequencies) as well as different Modes of transmission (i.e. voice, Morse code, teletype, etc).  I would like to choose different combinations of Modes and Bands to view my contacts.  My 2 groups (Band and Mode) have 8 or 9 checkboxes each.

My project can be found at:  http://www.paulkiener.com/Testing/index.html.  My code is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<p class="style4"><strong>TESTING:&nbsp; My Contacts</strong></p>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div id="map" style="width: 850px; height: 625px"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="MODE">
  <strong>MODE:</strong>&nbsp;<br />
  <span id="myMode">
  <strong>CW<img src="../Test/Learning%20Google%20maps/markers/mm_20_white.png" width="12" height="20" alt="white" /></strong><input type="checkbox" name="Mode" id="CWbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'CW')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>JT65<img src="../Test/Learning%20Google%20maps/markers/mm_20_blue.png" width="12" height="20" alt="blue" /></strong><input type="checkbox" name="Mode" id="JT65box" onclick="boxclick(this,'JT65')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>JT9<img src="../Test/Learning%20Google%20maps/markers/mm_20_brown.png" width="12" height="20" alt="brown" /></strong><input type="checkbox" name="Mode" id="JT9box" onclick="boxclick(this,'JT9')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>LSB<img src="../Test/Learning%20Google%20maps/markers/mm_20_gray.png" width="12" height="20" alt="gray" /></strong><input type="checkbox" name="Mode" id="LSBbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'LSB')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>MFSK16<img src="../Test/Learning%20Google%20maps/markers/mm_20_green.png" width="12" height="20" alt="green" /></strong><input type="checkbox" name="Mode" id="MFSK16box" onclick="boxclick(this,'MFSK16')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>PSK31<img src="../Test/Learning%20Google%20maps/markers/mm_20_orange.png" width="12" height="20" alt="orange" /></strong><input type="checkbox" name="Mode" id="PSK31box" onclick="boxclick(this,'PSK31')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>RTTY<img src="../Test/Learning%20Google%20maps/markers/mm_20_purple.png" width="12" height="20" alt="purple" /></strong><input type="checkbox" name="Mode" id="RTTYbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'RTTY')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>SSTV<img src="../Test/Learning%20Google%20maps/markers/mm_20_red.png" width="12" height="20" alt="red" /></strong><input type="checkbox" name="Mode" id="SSTVbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'SSTV')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>USB<img src="../Test/Learning%20Google%20maps/markers/mm_20_yellow.png" width="12" height="20" alt="yellow" /></strong><input type="checkbox" name="Mode" id="USBbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'USB')" /><br />
  </span>
</div>

<div class="BAND">
  <strong>BAND:</strong><br />
  <span id="myBand">
  <strong>10m:</strong><input type="checkbox" name="Band" id="10mbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'10m')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>12m:</strong><input type="checkbox" name="Band" id="12mbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'12m')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>15m:</strong><input type="checkbox" name="Band" id="15mbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'15m')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>17m:</strong><input type="checkbox" name="Band" id="17mbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'17m')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>20m:</strong><input type="checkbox" name="Band" id="20mbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'20m')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>30m:</strong><input type="checkbox" name="Band" id="30mbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'30m')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>40m:</strong><input type="checkbox" name="Band" id="40mbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'40m')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>80m:</strong><input type="checkbox" name="Band" id="80mbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'80m')" /><br />   
  </span>   
</div>
```

and:  **JavaScript:**

```
    var gmarkers = [];
var gicons = [];
var map = null;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
 { 
   size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
});

gicons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/mm_20_red.png");
var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('markers/mm_20_red.png');
var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('markers/mm_20_shadow.png');

function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
if ((typeof(iconColor)=="undefined") || (iconColor==null)) { 
  iconColor = "red"; 
}
if (!gicons[iconColor]) {
  gicons[iconColor] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/mm_20_"+ iconColor +".png");
} 
  return gicons[iconColor];
}

function Mode2color(Mode) {
var color = "red";
switch(Mode) {
case "CW": color = "white";
      break;
case "JT65":    color = "blue";
      break;
case "JT9":    color = "brown";
      break;
case "LSB":    color = "gray";
      break;
case "MFSK16":     color = "green";
      break;
case "PSK31":     color = "orange";
      break;
case "RTTY":    color = "purple";
      break;
case "SSTV":     color = "red";
      break;
case "USB":     color = "yellow";
      break;                                                              
default:   color = "black";
      break;
}
   return color;
}

gicons["CW"] = getMarkerImage(Mode2color("CW"));
gicons["JT65"] = getMarkerImage(Mode2color("JT65"));
gicons["JT9"] = getMarkerImage(Mode2color("JT9"));
gicons["LSB"] = getMarkerImage(Mode2color("LSB"));
gicons["MFSK16"] = getMarkerImage(Mode2color("MFSK16"));
gicons["PSK31"] = getMarkerImage(Mode2color("PSK31"));
gicons["RTTY"] = getMarkerImage(Mode2color("RTTY"));
gicons["SSTV"] = getMarkerImage(Mode2color("SSTV"));
gicons["USB"] = getMarkerImage(Mode2color("USB"));

// A function to create the marker and set up the event window
function createMarker(latlng,Call,html,Mode,Band,Contact) {
  var contentString = html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latlng,
     icon: gicons[Mode],
     shadow: iconShadow,
     map: map,
     title: name,
     zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
  });
// === Store the Mode and Band info as a marker properties ===
     marker.mycategory = Mode;
     marker.myaddress = Band;                                 
     marker.myname = Call;
     marker.mycontact = Contact;
     gmarkers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
     infowindow.open(map,marker);
     });
   }

// == shows all markers of a particular Mode, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
function show(Mode) {
  for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == Mode) {
      gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
    }
  }

// == check the checkbox ==
  document.getElementById(Mode+"box").checked = true;
 }

// == hides all markers of a particular Mode, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
   function hide(Mode) {
     for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
       if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == Mode) {
         gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
       }
     }

// == clear the checkbox ==
   document.getElementById(Mode+"box").checked = false;

// == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
   infowindow.close();
   }

// == a checkbox has been clicked ==
   function boxclick(box,Mode) {
     if (box.checked) {
       show(Mode);
     } else {
   hide(Mode);
     }
   }

   function boxclick(box,Band) {
     if (box.checked) {
       show(Band);
     } else {
       hide(Band);
     }
   }

   function myclick(i) {
     google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
   }

   function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.9339, -85.3880),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });

// Read the data
   downloadUrl("QSO.xml", function(doc) {
  var xml = xmlParse(doc);
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      // obtain the attribues of each marker
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var Name = markers[i].getAttribute("NAME");
      var QTH = markers[i].getAttribute("QTH");
      var Mode = markers[i].getAttribute("MODE");
      var Call = markers[i].getAttribute("CALL");
      var Band = markers[i].getAttribute("BAND");
      var Country = markers[i].getAttribute("COUNTRY")
      var State = markers[i].getAttribute("STATE")
      var Time = markers[i].getAttribute("TIME")
      var Contact = (Mode + Band)
      var html = "<b>" + Name + "  " + Call +"</b> <br/>" + QTH + " " + State + "<br/>" + Country + "<br/>" + Mode + "  " + Band + "</b> <br/>" + Time + "<br/>";
      // create the marker
      var marker = createMarker(point,Call,html,Mode,Band);
    }

// == show or hide the Mode and Bands initially ==
     show("CW");
     hide("JT65");
     hide("JT9");
     hide("LSB");
     hide("MFSK16");
     hide("PSK31");
     hide("RTTY");
     hide("SSTV");
     hide("USB");
     show("10m");
     show("12m");
     hide("15m");
     hide("17m");
     hide("20m");
     hide("30m");
     hide("40m");
     hide("80m");
   });
 }
```

My goal is to select one or more "`Modes`" and one or more "`Bands`" to display the proper combination chosen for viewing.  (e.g. I may want to see all "`CW`" and "`RTTY`" (`Modes`) on "`20m`" and "`40m`" (`Bands`)).  Currently, the checkboxes for "Mode" are working correctly; I need the "`Band`" checkboxes to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript select Google markers for all possibilities of checkbox conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528115/javascript-select-google-markers-for-all-possibilities-of-checkbox-conditions)

Comment: You defined boxclick function twice.  Change one of them and update your checkboxes, hopefully should help.

Comment: @Will, Thank you for your quick response. I have attempted to redefine the boxclick function; changed "boxclick" in first instance to "boxclickM" and in the second instance to "boxclickB".  As well, in the html section, changed the onclick=boxclick(this,'10m') to onclick=boxclickB(this,'10m').  (I changed all the "boxclick" to either "boxclickB" or "boxclickM" as needed).  I notice that I must be getting closer to my desired resolution because if I didn't change the html, I would get an "undefined" error.  With the change in the html as well, there are no error messages.

Comment: @geocodezip, thank you very much for your quick reply.  Your approach is different from the first suggestion (I think).  Not sure if I can handle the suggestion of unique values for the different checkboxes selected.